# Edit a line with sed

Tags: shell, unix

I have input that contains structures that are defined with a typedef. 
I later use these to initialize variables in my main function.

For example:

```
typedef struct {
   int numer;
   int denom;
} Rational;

int main()
{
Rational half, *newf = malloc(sizeof(Rational));

half = (Rational){ 1, 2 };
*newf = (Rational){ 2, 3 };
}
```

Here is what I want to do:
I want to convert the two initialization lines into function calls.

For example:

```
half = (Rational){ 1, 2 };
```

should turn into:

```
init_Rational( &half,  1, 2  );
```

and

```
*newf = (Rational){ 2, 3 };
```

should turn into

```
init_Rational( newf,  2, 3  );
```

The trick is to remember that Rational was defined as a struct earlier and replace the initializations with function calls. It doesn't have to be called Rational, it could be any name.

Once it recognizes that the declaration is a struct typedef, it should do the following as shown above.

Turn:

```
something = (someStructName){ data1, data2, data3.. };
```

into

```
init_someStructName( &something, data1, data2, data3.. );
```

Or for pointers...Turn:

```
*something = (someStructName){ data1, data2, data3.. };
```

into

```
init_someStructName( something, data1, data2, data3.. );
```

Can someone help me out here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty tricky problem, because needing to dynamically detect struct names means you can't write the entire regular expression in advance.

Here is one potential solution, assuming your file name is foo.c:

```
sed -n '/^typedef struct/,/^}/{/^}/{s/.* \(.*\);/\1/p}}' foo.c | xargs -I {} sed -i -e 's/^\(\s*\)\*\(\w*\) = ('{}'){\(.*\)};/\1init_'{}'( \2,\3);/' -e 's/^\(\s*\)\(\w*\) = ('{}'){\(.*\)};/\1init_'{}'( \&\2,\3);/' foo.c
```

This does one pass with `sed` to print out each struct name on a line by itself, and then uses `xargs` to construct an additional `sed` command for each struct to perform the replacements on the file in place.

If your version of `sed` doesn't support the `\s` or `\w` shortcuts, you can use `[ \t]` instead of `\s` and `[_a-zA-Z0-9]` instead of `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

Almost unreadable!

```
sed -e 's/\(\**[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\) *= *( *\([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\) *) *{\([^}]*\)} *;/init_\2(\&\1,\3);/'
```

Note: it's a single line
Note2: I have assumed that there may be only spaces as possible separators (no TAB)
Note3: The form "`*x`" is left unchanged, since it's transformed into `&*x`, that it's correct. I have assumed that there aren't spaces between "*" and the identifier;

Comment: I think one of the requirements was that the replacement would only be done for structs that were defined inside of the same file as the initialization.